# using pandoc to generate pdf for Heroku

Tags: python, django, pandoc, pypandoc

On my Django site I have a button that will create a word document and covert it into pdf file to show it to the user in a new window. Now this is done by reading a word document using `docx` and then `docx2pdf` to make the conversation.

My problem is that when I launch it on Heroku to make it live, because heroku runs on linux this means that my document wont be created because im trying to generate it with docx.

I think it may be possible to use `pandoc`. However I am have trouble implementing it.
below is the word document generation and pdf generation without trying to implement `pandoc`. how can I implement pandoc with the code below:

```
import docx

def making_a_doc_function(request):

 doc = docx.Document()
 doc.add_heading("hello")

 doc.save('thisisdoc.docx')
 convert("thisisdoc.docx", "output.pdf")
 pdf = open('output.pdf', 'rb')
 response = FileResponse(pdf)
return response
```

pandoc documentation: https://pypi.org/project/pyandoc/

Answer (score 0):

Heroku itself does not prevent you from creating docx files using python-docx, the only issue is storing the output files to external storage (python-docx does not work with remote locations for neither upload nor saving). I needed to write custom processors to make it work with AWS S3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29782115)